# Standard Python libraries and Unicode

Tags: python, unicode

I have been reading left right and centre about unicode and python. I think I understand what encoding/decoding is, yet as soon as I try to use a standard library method manipulating a file name, I get the infamous:

```
 UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe9' in position 19:
 ordinal not in range(128)
```

In this case \xe9 stands for 'é', and it doesn't matter if I call it from a os.path.join() or a shutil.copy(), it throws the same error. From what I understand it has to do with the default encoding of python. I try to change it with:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

Nothing changes. If I type:

```
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')
```

it tells me:

```
ImportError: cannot import name setdefaultencoding
```

What I really don't understand is why it works when I type it in the terminal, '\xe9' and all. Could someone please explain to me why this is happening/how to get around it?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should decode manually the filename with the correct encoding (latin1?) *before* os.path.join

btw: # -*- coding: utf-8 -*- refers to the string literals in your .py file

[effbot](http://effbot.org/zone/unicode-objects.htm) has some good infos

Comment: What I had not realised was that os.path.walk hands the given function encoded strings. A quick .decode('latin1') right at the beginning of the walking function solved the problem for me. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Filenames on *nix cannot be manipulated as `unicode`. The filename must be encoded to match [the charset of the filesystem](http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html#sys.getfilesystemencoding) and then used.

Answer (score 1):

You should not touch the default encoding. It is best practice and highly recommendable to keep it with 'ascii' and convert your data properly to utf-8 on the output side.